# Fragment recreation on back from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-savedstate

I have two activities, A and B.
Activity A, has one fragment F, added dynamically via a transaction. From F, I start activity B (F.getActivity.startActivity(intent)). When I press the back button, F gets recreated. Can I avoid that?

If not, I understand I can save the fragment state, but the savedInstanceState bundle is always null. I found you must set an id in the XML, but as the fragment is dynamically created, I don't know how to set it.

Thanks.

Comment: possibly it is duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990868/fragment-is-recreate-on-back-press-from-other-fragment?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

you can manage it by adding fragment to backstack by below code

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.containerView, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("test");
```

and pop back the fragment state by below one

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack("test", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

hope this will be helpful.